# Tripwire - Policy Test with white circle on its icon

Tags: tripwire

What does the white circle on the icon mean?

When it is checked further, it does not have the last checked date or status.

Thank you.

[image: Tripwire Tests with white circle on the icon]

[image: Tripwire Tests with white circle on the icon]

Answer (score 0):

this is caused by the rule and the dependent policy test not being linked. most common occurrence of this is if a policy check was done before the rule(s) could baseline. to re-establish the link run the rule(s) again, than run the policy check. If the white/grey dot persists check for any rule run errors on your nodes.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).